# How to plot ground truth bboxs using tensorFlow 2 Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to visualize the ground truth bboxs using the docs, as follows:

```
viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'],
          detections['detection_classes'],
          detections['detection_scores'],
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          groundtruth_box_visualization_color='black',
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,
          min_score_thresh=.10,
          agnostic_mode=False)
```

But, looks like `groundtruth_box_visualization_color='black'` doesn't works, because after infering a testing sample it doesnt shows the ground truth bboxs, any idea how to fix this?

I added to pipeline.config file the following:

```
eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  visualization_export_dir: "/home/ambigus9/models/research/images/eval"
  visualize_groundtruth_boxes: true
  batch_size: 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No, i don't get any error, just not plotting ground truth bboxs on testing images

Comment: Add the output image. Also, did you check if the model is actually detecting something in the image?

Comment: Currently i'm limited because image sensitive, i can't public one, but i can tell that yes! the model is drawing bboxs with class and scoring, but no gth (ground truth bboxs), any suggestion? I just adding eval config dict from pipeline.config